# Customizar Hash de autenticação Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-auth

Seguinte, eu tenho um banco especifico com colunas especificas e um método de Hash especifico, estou migrando para o Laravel seguinte a estrutura multi tenancy.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer com que o laravel ignore o Bcrypt e aceite a minha forma de Hash?

Se existe, como poderia fazer ?

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste [link do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42704782/changing-laravel-5-4-password-encryption-and-table-column-names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta dar uma olhada em como o `hashing` padrão funciona.

Há no `Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider` o seguinte método

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('hash', function () { return new BcryptHasher; });
}
```

o que significa, por padrão, que você está usando o `BcryptHasher` como instância.

Se você deseja implementar o `hash` sozinho, você terá que criar seu próprio provedor de serviços(`Provider`) e fachadas(`Facades`) para `hashing` e depois trocar as implementações padrão do arquivo `config/app.php`.

Mais precisamente, você vai querer trocar na matriz de provedores

`Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class`,
com o seu próprio provedor de serviços(`providers`), e o mesmo vale para o `array` de `aliases` no mesmo arquivo.

Então, como um exemplo, dê uma olhada em como o `BcryptHasher` implementa uma interface, e sua implementação de hash deve implementar a mesma interface.

Isso estenderia o `hash` no Laravel.

> Tópicos complementares
>
> [Mudar a hash usada para o login no laravel 5.4](https://www.schoolofnet.com/forum/topico/mudar-a-hash-usada-para-o-login-no-laravel-54-369)
>
> [Adding Custom User Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)
>
> [Custom auth and hashing laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667257/custom-auth-and-hashing-laravel-5-1)
>
> [Creating a Hashing Manager For Our Custom Laravel Hashing
>   Implementations](https://stillat.com/blog/2016/11/30/creating-a-hashing-manager-for-our-custom-laravel-hashing-implementations)